# Accessing Excel's Custom Footer dialog box w/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to access Excel's built-in custom footer dialog box with VBA? I'd like to access the actual dialog box; I know how to directly modify the footer via `ActiveSheet.PageSetup`.

I can open the Page Setup box via `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPageSetup).Show` but I'm not able to get to the Header/Footer tab, then Custom Footer.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPageSetup).Show
Application.SendKeys "h" 'Go to the Header/Footer tab
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}", True 'Go to Custom Footer
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:** 
Thanks for your responses thus far, and my apologies for not being clearer.

As noted above, I understand how to use `ActiveSheet.PageSetup`to modify the Left/Center/Right footer fields; however, I'd like to *directly access the Custom Footer dialog box so that non-technical colleagues can easily modify these fields*, in a familiar manner, as opposed to having them look through the VBA and changing the existing text strings and/or codes.

Comment: Assuming what you're *actually* trying to do is to programmatically modify the header/footer of the document.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call any dialogbox. You can access header/footer directly:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&D  &B&ITime:&I&B&T"
```

More at [MSDN - Formatting and VBA Codes for Headers and Footers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225426(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise it would be

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&D  &B&ITime:&I&B&T"
```

for the footer.

There are three points you can access, LeftFooter, CenterFooter, and RightFooter.  It will be the same for the header.

This question has already been asked and answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542260/replace-text-on-header-and-footer-of-excel-file)